# How to use StorageProvider.Download(...) to download private files?

Tags: genexus

When using "StorageProvider.Download(...)", it seems that I can only download files uploaded to the public storage.

Is there a way to download private uploaded files to my server local storage?

I´m using Azure external storage provider.

Thanks!

Example:

```
// In this case the file is downloaded to the local filesystem:
&LocalFile.Source = 'LocalFile.txt'
&Result = &StorageProvider.Download('AzurePublicFile.txt', &LocalFile, &Messages)

// In this case the file is not downloaded locally, it only loads a reference to the URI in the Azure blob container:
&LocalFile.Source = 'LocalFile.txt'
&Result = &StorageProvider.GetPrivate('AzurePrivateFile.txt', &LocalFile, 5, &Messages)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
StorageProvider.GetPrivate(...., &File)
&URL = &File.GetURI()
&HttpClient.Execute('GET', &URL)
&HttpClient.ToFile("C:\....")
```

Update: StorageProvider.DownloadPrivate() will be available in GeneXus 16 Upgrade 2.

Comment: Thanks Gonzalo,

I´ve tried using "StorageProvider.GetPrivate", but it only loads de URI of the file in the remote container.
I want to download the file and store it in the local filesystem for further processing.

Comment: Added an example in my post

Comment: @Matias, your're right. We may be missing a downloadprivate method. Try an alternative way in my post above.

Comment: Thanks! The alternative way does the job. Marking as answered!